# can I use thymeleaf instead of axios in react as HTTP client

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Hello there I am trying to develop a spring boot application but I am facing the issue of moving to javascript framework like react with axios (http client) and I am looking for other way to do that I know that react will give better performance but is it possible to build it with thymleaf only and how to implement calls in thymeleaf I have the following example of code which is simple.

in case of react the use of axios is implemented like this

```
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

my controller class is implemented as following

```
package com.site.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.site.demo.entity.Employee;
import com.site.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository eRepo;

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){
        return eRepo.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

the result of the controller

```
0   
id  1
name    "islam"
department  "IT"
location    "Saudi Arabia"
1   
id  2
name    "ahmed"
department  "Managment"
location    "Saudi Arabia"
```

now how to use this results in thymeleaf and is it possible to be used in thymeleaf only without the need for Single Page Application like react the main point is to place it in html only front-end using thymeleaf